# Unity Collision Detection - Adding GUI Score on Collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, detection

I am making a pinball game in Unity, and I have an issue. When the pinball collides with a cylinder to add points to the score, it does not work. I have tagged the cylinders in Unity and have attached this script to the pinball. It doesn't even show up in the debug log.

Thanks for any advice.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Score : MonoBehaviour {
public int scorePoint = 10;
public int MaxScore;
public Text ScoreText;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    ScoreText = GetComponent<Text>();
    ScoreText.text = "Score: " + scorePoint;
}

void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Cylinder")
    {
        Debug.Log("Collision detected");
        scorePoint+=10;

    }
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}
}
```

Comment: You know, when your question gets rejected on Unity Answers for a justified reason and clues to resolve your problem, it's quite disappointing to see you asking the exact same question here on StackOverflow. Not being able to make a **little** research to solve your problems won't get you far.

Comment: Also **Tigger** and **Collision** aren't the same things... Try using `OnCollisionEnter()`.

Comment: @Hellium Truly fascinating I will alert the media.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have a box collider on each object. OnTriggerEnter is only called when two box collider hit each other. This is the most likely culprit of why its not working but without more information I can't guarantee it.

Comment: So I enlarged the size of the colliders and it managed to trigger and showed up on the debug log! However the score is still stuck at zero. Is there a logic error to cause this?

Comment: You are incrementing the score in memory but you are never updating the text. In the if statement set ScoreText.text = scorepoint

Comment: Also if its 0 instead of 10 to start with its probably because you have it set as 0 in the inspector. If you don't want to edit the number in the inspector make the variable private.

Comment: So I learned the collision is detected when I set the collider to "is trigger". However when that box is checked, the ball goes right through the object, and the console says

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Score.OnTriggerEnter (UnityEngine.Collider other) (at Assets/Score.cs:24)"

Comment: There's plenty of tutorials on how to properly set up Box Colliders for triggered events. I suggest watching a few. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/physics/colliders-triggers

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your pinball game.